# Select distinct rows based on MAX value of a certain column

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I am retrieving results using Teradata SQL assistant and need help de-duping some data. I only want to return results that have the max VRSN_ID based on PROD_ID.

I tried something like this in the code but did not work as desired:

```html
FROM( 
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
 PARTITION BY PROD_ID 
 ORDER BY  VRSN_ID DESC) AS ROWNUM 
 FROM tblDATA)
```

Current Result:

```html
CMPNY_CD VRSN_ID PROD_ID
ABC 1 33303115
ABC 1 33303115
ABC 1 33303115
ABC 2 33303115
ABC 4 32632795
ABC 2 32632795
```

Desired Result:

```html
CMPNY_CD VRSN_ID PROD_ID
ABC 2 33303115
ABC 4 32632795
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `qualify`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblDATA
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROD_ID ORDER BY VRSN_ID DESC) = 1
```

`QUALIFY` is like `HAVING` or `WHERE`, except you can use window fucntions.